# Approximation to Lattice points inside circle

Tags: number-theory

In the Wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem), there is an approximation that $N(r)=\pi r^2+E(r)$ and then it says that Gauss managed to prove that $E(r)\leq2 \sqrt2 \pi r$ can anyone prove the original formula and tell me how Gauss got his approximation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Around each lattice point consider the axe-parallel square of side length $1$ and the lattice point as center.
The area of the circle is $\pi r^2$ is approximately $N(r)$ (the sum of square areas for interior points) and the difference comes only from lattice points whose associated square is neither fully inside nor fully outside the circle. But then such squares are fully outside the circle with radius $r-\frac12\sqrt 2$ and fully inside the circle with radius $r+\frac12\sqrt 2$. In other words, if $r>\frac12\sqrt 2$ then 
$$ \pi\left(r-\frac12\sqrt 2\right)^2\le N(r)\le  \pi\left(r+\frac12\sqrt 2\right)^2.$$
This already gives $E(r)\le \pi r\sqrt 2+\frac12\pi$, which is better than needed.

For $r\le \frac12\sqrt 2$, note that $N(r)=1$ and this may differ from $\pi r^2$ by more than $2\pi r$, so the claim does not even hold for all $r$!