# Number of points inside a shape on the Cartesian plane

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I was wondering if there is a formula which can help in finding number of points on a shape on the Cartesian plane, knowing that the shape isn't a rectangle nor a square.

For example: consider an ellipse of equation $ax^2 + by^2 \le c$, Calculate number of points inside that ellipse (number of integer solutions for the equation).

Comment: Do you mean $ax^2+bx^2<c$ so points inside?

Comment: yes, sorry about that, coffeemath

Comment: (So points inside or on, since used $\le$ (inclusive).

Comment: The term "shape" is rather vague, and very broad. What kinds of shapes do you have in mind? Just ellipses?

Comment: Ellipses and circles are the only closed shapes which can be expressed by equations (non piece wise functions), I think.

Comment: @anaspcpro This is *very* far from true. For example, there are also the "shapes" defined by $x^n+y^n=c$, which are closed and nonempty if $n$ is even  and $c\geq0$, and there are many, *many* more such polynomial equations. And going beyond polynomials, there are so many equations that you don't even want to think about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know the following related facts.

Given a simple polygon constructed on a grid of equal-distanced points (i.e., points with integer coordinates) such that all the polygon's vertices are grid points, [Pick's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem) provides a simple formula for calculating the area A of this polygon in terms of the numbers of grid points in the interior located in the polygon and on the boundary placed on the polygon's perimeter.

A number of grid points inside a sufficiently fat figure appoximately equals its area. For instance, Gauss's circle problem asks for the number $N(r)$ of grid points inside the boundary of a circle of radius $r$ with centered at the origin. Gauss showed that $N(r)=\pi r^2+E(r)$, where $|E(r)|\le 2\sqrt{2}\pi r$,  see also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/520375/approximation-to-lattice-points-inside-circle) answer. Writing $|E(r)|\le Cr^\theta$, the best bounds on $\theta$ are $1/2<\theta\le 131/208\simeq 0.62981$. For the references  and the story of the bounds see [Gauss's circle problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssCircleProblem.html) by Eric W. Weisstein at Wolfram MathWorld. There is also noted that  the problem has also been extended to conics, ellipsoids (Hardy 1915), and higher dimensions.

When I was a schoolboy at a contest I was given a problem to show that if an area of a figure is less than $1$ then there is a translated copy of the figure without grid points.

Comment: Thanks so much for this useful information, Alex Ravsky. This is the only answer so I don't have another choice other than rewarding you the bounty,if this question got more attentions I might just up vote your answer; as it had useful information **not** including ellipses.